# Aproximar gráficos

Tags: r

Como faço para aproximar os gráficos gerados pelo comando a seguir?

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
barplot(1:4) 
barplot(1:4)
barplot(1:4)
barplot(1:4)
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Editei sua pergunta para remover as saudações pois costumamos manter o texto o mais limpo possível para focar na sua dúvida sobre programação. Caso tenha interesse em visitar uma parte do site que não é voltado para tirar dúvidas pode conhecer o [chat]. Se tiver dúvidas quanto ao funcionamento, regras e procedimentos do site visite o [meta] :)

Answer (score 5):

Para regular a distância na "altura" e na "largura" entre os gráficos você precisa controlar o parâmetro `mai` dentro do comando `par`:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2), mai = c(0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3))
barplot(1:4) 
barplot(1:4)
barplot(1:4)
barplot(1:4)
```

Se você quiser controlar as margens de fora do gráfico, aí você precisa alterar os parâmetros `oma`:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2), mai = c(0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3), oma = rep(0.1,4))
barplot(1:4) 
barplot(1:4)
barplot(1:4)
barplot(1:4)
```

Comment: Com esse comando não estou conseguindo inserir o título do eixo y. O comando ylab="teste" parece não funcionar.

Comment: você quer colocar o título no eixo y geral, ou o título no eixo de cada gráfico? Se for em cada gráfico, aí é da forma usual. Se for um título no eixo y geral, aí vai pelo `mtext`, se não me engano

Comment: Obrigado. Vou tentar.

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se essa solução que eu vou te sugerir é exatamente a solução para o seu problema. Da forma como você expôs o problema a ideia seria aproximar os gráficos feitos com o R Base. **Entretanto** caso o seu gráfico de enquadre na seguinte situação:

1. existe uma variável categórica (ou grupo) que separa os dados;
2. quero fazer um `barplot` para cada categoria;

nesse caso você poderia utilizar os `facets` do `ggplot2` que dão uma apresentação melhor ao gráfico e uma consistência na apresentação. No seguinte gráfico eu vou criar um conjunto de dados fictício e uma variável para a categoria:

```
library(ggplot2)
data("diamonds")
ggplot(data=diamonds, aes(x = clarity)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  facet_wrap(~cut)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

aqui eu estou fazendo um gráfico de barras com relação a claridade dos diamantes, mas fazendo um gráfico de barras para cada categoria de corte. Veja a consistência da apresentação: os nomes das categorias vão no topo dos gráficos e as escalas são consistentes ao longo dos gráficos.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Caro @VitorHugo caso a resposta tenha lhe agradado, mas não foi sua resposta escolhida, você pode votar na resposta como reconhecimento. Sempre que você vota positivamente em um resposta, mesmo que não for a sua escolhida, o autor da resposta ganha pontos de reputação. É uma forma de encorajar os autores e dar um retorno positivo ;-)